# reduce javascript array of objects

Tags: javascript, filter, reduce

I have an Array of objects and I need to return this collection like Object and they key-names need to be indexes of length. I need to filter this object for it values.

Here is my code:

```js
const data = [
  { index: 1, value: "111" },
  { index: 2, value: "121" },
  { index: 3, value: "111" },
  { index: 5, value: "111" },
  { index: 6, value: "121" },
  { index: 7, value: "121" },
];

const getGroupBy = (data) => {
  return data.reduce((acc, curr, currIndex, arr) => {
    const val = curr.value;
    const idx = curr.index;
    const fValues = arr.filter((el) => el.value === val).map(el => el.index);
    if (acc.hasOwnProperty(currIndex)) {
      acc[currIndex] = arr.filter((el) => el.value === val);
    } else {
      Object.assign(acc, { [0]: [idx] });
    }
    return acc;
  }, {});
};

console.log(getGroupBy(data));
```

My expected output is :

```json
{
    0: [1,3,5],
    1: [2,6,7]
}
```

Comment: key ```value``` of each object is a rule for grouping.

Comment: it looks like the 0 and 1 are the index arrays for 111 and 121

Comment: I have solution for two methods: `map` and `filter` and lodash `group` and this is it: 

`
const lodashGroupBy = groupBy(nonUniqueElements, 'value');
Object.keys(lodashGroupBy).map((key, i) => {
                return new Object({[i]: lodashGroupBy[key].map((el) => el.index)});
            });
`
but I need do this with reduce for avoid some iteration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could group and assign the values to an object.

```js
const
    data = [{ index: 1, value: "111" }, { index: 2, value: "121" }, { index: 3, value: "111" }, { index: 5, value: "111" }, { index: 6, value: "121" }, { index: 7, value: "121" }],
    result = Object.assign(
        {},
        Object.values(data.reduce((r, { index, value }) => ((r[value] ??= []).push(index), r), {}))
    );

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 3):

Is this not more useful, to key the arrays by their values instead of 0,1?

Anyway here is how to reduce and how to get either 0,1 keyed or keyed on value

```js
const data = [
  { index: 1, value: "111" },
  { index: 2, value: "121" },
  { index: 3, value: "111" },
  { index: 5, value: "111" },
  { index: 6, value: "121" },
  { index: 7, value: "121" },
];

const indicii = data.reduce((acc,{index,value}) => {
  (acc[value] ??= []).push(index);
  return acc;
},{})
console.log({...Object.values(indicii)})
// or 
console.log(indicii);
```

Interesting method suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75916925/295783)

```js
const data = [
  { index: 1, value: "111" },
  { index: 2, value: "121" },
  { index: 3, value: "111" },
  { index: 5, value: "111" },
  { index: 6, value: "121" },
  { index: 7, value: "121" },
];

const indicii = data
  .reduce((acc,{index,value},i, arr) => {
    (acc[value] ??= []).push(index);
    return i < arr.length ? acc : {...Object.values(acc) }; // return the requested format at end
  },{});

console.log(indicii);
```

Comment: to get what OP wants maybe {...Object.values(indici)}

Comment: sorry i meant `{...Object.values(indicii)}`

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to go through the step

1. {value: [index]}
2. {0: value}

this step is help your code more cleaner

```js
  const data = [
    { index: 1, value: '111' },
    { index: 2, value: '121' },
    { index: 3, value: '111' },
    { index: 5, value: '111' },
    { index: 6, value: '121' },
    { index: 7, value: '121' },
  ];

  const getGroupBy = (data) => {
    return data.reduce((acc, curr) => {
      if (acc[curr.value]) acc[curr.value].push(curr.index);
      else acc[curr.value] = [curr.index];
      return acc;
    }, {});
  };
  console.log(getGroupBy(data));
  console.log({ ...Object.values(getGroupBy(data)) });
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code, I used reduce but last iteration, I changed the output to the desired one.

This is useful manytimes to get the desired output. when index is for last item, we are done with all the elements.

```js
const data = [
  { index: 1, value: "111" },
  { index: 2, value: "121" },
  { index: 3, value: "111" },
  { index: 5, value: "111" },
  { index: 6, value: "121" },
  { index: 7, value: "121" },
];

const getGroupBy = (data) => {
  return data.reduce((acc, curr, index) => {
    const val = curr.value;
    const idx = curr.index;
    var key  = val;
     
    if (!acc[key]) {
      acc[key] = [];
    }
    acc[key].push(idx);

     if (index == data.length-1) {
      return Object.values(acc).reduce((a,c, i)=> { a[i]=c; return a;}, {});
    }
    return acc;
  }, {});
};


console.log(getGroupBy(data))
```

Comment: Interesting way to move the last formatting inside the reduce